# JAXB marshalling big objects

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, java-ee-7

We are currently having some problems with JaxB performance when marshalling to xml large objects. Basicaly the marshalling process is very slow. We are basically marshaling like this:

```
final JAXBContext context = JaxBContextCache.getContext();
final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, SCHEMA_LOCATION);
m.marshal(obj, file);
```

Any suggestion what we can do to improve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the means of "large objects" and "very slow" ?

Comment: To give you an example - marshaling to an XML file of 2MB takes approx 90s.

Comment: Are you sure it's the code that's slow? I see you are marshalling to a file. So it could be the filesystem also. Even some overly active virusscanner that's kicking in every time Java is writing to disk.